# google-chrome, when ran in the background through bash, still outputs errors, despite 2>&1 > /dev/null

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, google-chrome

When I run `google-chrome 2>&1 > /dev/null &` and then go back to the prompt and then visit a website with, say, an invalid cert, I still get errors output to my console's screen. eg.

```
neubert@LAPTOP:~/folder$ [32094:32113:1228/101803.899469:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
[32094:32113:1228/101804.014732:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
```

I don't understand. `2>&1` should be redirecting stderr to stdout and then `> /dev/null` should be redirecting both to /dev/null. If that's a correct analysis of what that command is doing then why am I still getting random messages from the browser? And how do I make it so that I don't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To discard any output so `STDOUT` & `STDERR`, you need to redirect like that :

```
google-chrome > /dev/null 2>&1
google-chrome &> /dev/null
```

Your syntax is incorrect, you are only redirecting `STDOUT` it's for this reason you got messages in prompt. The order of redirections is significant :

```
ls > dirlist 2>&1
```

The above command will directs both standard output (`STDOUT`) **AND** standard error (`STDERR`) to the file *dirlist*.

While this command :

```
ls 2>&1 > dirlist
```

directs **only** the standard output (`STDOUT`) to file *dirlist*, because the standard error **was made a copy of the standard output before** the standard output was redirected to dirlist.

Where *dirlist* is equal to `/dev/null` in that case.

[Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)